# How to remove column spacing staggered grid view

Tags: android, staggered-gridview

[image: column spacing]
I am using staggered grid view to display elements like this but elements in a row are not filling empty space, how to remove this extra space so elements can span between columns.

XML layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_cropgrow"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_lbl_cropgrow"
                app:spanCount="3"
                tools:itemCount="5"
                tools:listitem="@layout/rcv_items_selected_crop"/>
```

Comment: Please provide your layout and/or code to help troubleshoot.

Comment: whats the xml look like for the grid item